# how do I render p5 canvas to Cloudinary without downloading the picture

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, cloudinary

Im working in a machine learning + p5 proyect for making visual art.

I'm using p5 to generate the canvas and using node + express connected to cloudinary (using mongoose models to fetch info back ).

I'm trying to upload the rendered canvas to cloudinary and then show it to the user.

I want to upload the canvas saved.

There are mainly two ways of saving canvas in p5, one is with the function save which autmatically download the file, the other is saveFrames which works with a callback who provides you the picture for you to handle it.

Is there a way to upload the picture without downloading , just click a button and upload directly to cloudinary?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could get the image data from the canvas and send it to your server using ajax or something of those sorts, then convert it to an actual image then send it to cloudinary. To get the image data, you need to get the canvas element that is being rendered on, then use the method `toDataURL()` storing it in a variable. Then sending that to the server and converting it to an image by decoding it (baseg4). Finally, sending it to the server. There are probably other methods, but this is just an idea

Comment: Are you using Processing, the desktop programming language also known as "p5", or are you talking about p5js, the Javascript library that is entirely API-incompatible with Processing (but allows for the same kind of visual programming)?

Comment: thank you for the answers guys, i made some advance , ill share in case someone is with the same problem that me.

i made a function called each time i touch the canvas and buffers the image in Base64 and send it to the server. it works in the first seconds when the canvas has only some lines on it.
but then i got a 413 (Payload Too Large) in the browser server. i tried extending the limit of the body parser, but nothing..

Comment: here is the home-made code 


function canvasPressed() {

    let url = '/picture/add'
  
    saveFrames('out', 'png', 1, 1, data => {
        httpPost(url,'text', data, function () {console.log("done")});
    });
}